# Fazendo contas função Javascript

Tags: javascript, funções, return

Olá, tenho que multiplicar usando a função, são 3 cálculos. Quando faço a seguinte estrutura, somente o último resultado aparece no return.

```
function multiplicar(){
  return (7*5), (7*10), (50*0.5);
}
```

Tentei usar variação e também não deu certo

```
function multiplicar(numeroA,numeroB,numeroC){
  var numeroA = 7*5;
  var numeroB = 7*10;
  var numeroC = 50*0.5
  var resultado = numeroA,numeroB,numeroC;
  return resultado
```

Poderiam me ajudar apontando onde estou errando
Obrigada :)

Comment: Não é possível de retornar múltiplos valores com virgula como está a fazer. Mostre também o local onde está a usar o suposto retorno da função.

Answer (score 0):

Olá.

O operador vírgula avalia o valor de seus operandos (da esquerda para a direita) e retorna o valor do último operando.

Use `+` em vez do `,`.

Solução:

```js
console.log(multiplicar([7,5],[7,10],[50,0.5]));
// retorna: 130

function multiplicar(numA,numB,numC){
  var numeroA = numA[0]*numA[1];
  var numeroB = numB[0]*numB[1];
  var numeroC = numC[0]*numC[1];
  var resultado = numeroA+numeroB+numeroC;
  return resultado;
}
```

Caso queria que retorne cada resultado:

```js
console.log(multiplicar([7,5],[7,10],[50,0.5]));
/* retorna:
35
70
25
*/

function multiplicar(numA,numB,numC){
  var numeroA = numA[0]*numA[1];
  var numeroB = numB[0]*numB[1];
  var numeroC = numC[0]*numC[1];
  var resultado = numeroA+"\n"+numeroB+"\n"+numeroC;
  return resultado;
}
```

Fonte:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operador_Virgula

Comment: eu consigo validar esses valores para que cada um apareça em uma linha, quebra de linha no caso?

Comment: Sim. Use `var resultado = numeroA+"\n"+numeroB+"\n"+numeroC;`

Answer (score 0):

voce quer multiplicar os resultados e exibir em uma string ? Recomendo usar:

```
const multiplicar = (n1, n2) => n1 * n2 
const resultado = multiplicar(7,5) + ', ' + multiplicar(7,10) + ', ' + multiplicar(50,0.5)
console.log(resultado)
// 30,70,25
```

Comment: Obrigada, deu certinho :)